# Unix Scripting - Finding Minimum and Maximum (Bash Shell)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

My code below is part of an assignment, but I'm racking my head against the desk not understanding why it won't assign a "MIN" value. I tried assigning the MIN and MAX to ${LIST[0]} just to have the first index in place, but it returns the whole array, which doesn't make sense to me. I'm executing this on a CentOS VM (which I can't see making a difference). I know the beginning of the first and second "if" statements need better logic, but I'm more concerned on the MIN and MAX outputs.

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST=()

read -p "Enter a set of numbers. " LIST

MIN=
MAX=

if [ ${#LIST[*]} == 0 ]; then echo "More numbers are needed."; fi

if [ ${#LIST[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
        for i in ${LIST[@]}; do
                if [[ $i -gt $MAX ]]; then
                        MAX=$i
                fi

                if [[ $i -lt $MIN ]]; then
                        MIN=$i
                fi
        done

echo Max is: $MAX.
echo Min is: $MIN.

fi
```

Comment: You need to review what type LIST is?  You set it as an empty array and then assign a scalar value using read.  You need to include the -a switch to read to maintain LIST as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is almost functional.

1. Since *$LIST* is an array, not a variable, change `read -p "Enter a set of numbers. " LIST` to:

   `read -p "Enter a set of numbers. " -a LIST`
2. Move the *$MIN* and *$MAX* init code down 5 lines, (just before the `for` loop):

   ```
   MIN=
   MAX=
   ```

   ...and change it to:

   ```
   MIN=${LIST[0]}
   MAX=$MIN
   ```

And it'll work.  Test:

```
echo 3 5 6 | ./minmax.sh
```

Output:

```
Max is: 6.
Min is: 3.
```

Comment: I like this solution. I had originally added an OR to my MIN logic (..|| MIN -eq "") and it worked out. What I had failed to remember, being use to other programming languages, is that these were string literals and not integers. It made sense as to why ${LIST[0]} was printing out the whole set up numbers (or single string). Thanks, @agc.